# Easiest Way to Migrate data from MySQL to MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb, migration, import

My latest IT project has me working with MongoDB for the first time. While I have a bit (very little) experience with NoSQL, I have always mostly worked with MySQL using Workbench.

I need to migrate the data from a MySQL database into MongoDB as my employer is switching over from the former to the latter.

Can someone suggest what might be the easiest way to do that?

Thanks a bundle!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrating between a RDBMS and a NoSQL DB is not the easiest thing.
If you can dump your data to JSON (or XML), I know that [Navicat for MongoDB](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mongodb) can import data in either of those formats.

I know that [MySQL workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import.html) can export in JSON format.  You might also want to try a [Navicat for MySQL](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql).  I use it and I know that it can export to either of those formats.

Navicat products aren't free, but both come with a 14 day trial.  That should be plenty long enough to get the job done.

Let me know how that works for you!

Dave

Comment: Thanks Dave!  That worked quite well.  I had to run the import a couple of times to get the data formatting just right, but overall, is was a fairly easy process.  I used MySQL Workbench to export and Navicat for MongoDB to import.

Michael

Comment: @MichaelTremblay - Please report back later on how MongoDB compares to MySQL.

Comment: Hi Rick,

Being a NoSQL database, MongoDB is a very different animal than MySQL.  Being used to the latter, getting the hang of MongoDB has required a substantial learning curve.  Having said that, I strongly believe that NoSQL is the way of the future as traditional DBMSes just haven't been able to handle the quantities of data and real-time requirements of modern applications.  Fortunately, using Navicat for MongoDB has greatly facilitated the switch from MySQL to MongoDB.  It has a lot of wizards and tools that make the DBA's job much easier.   Michael